# Matlab Error : Matrix dimension must agree

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in nusrat (line 13)
a0=1/(r+v.*t)

```
clc
clear all
close all
r=1.5*1000
d=2*1000
v=(60*1000)/3600
W=10^6
t=0:1/W:0.02
c=3*10^8
tou0=(r+v.*t)/c
tou1=(2*d-r-v.*t)/c
TD=tou1-tou0
a0=1/(r+v.*t)
a1=1/(2*d-r-v.*t)
fc=900*10^6
phi1=-2*pi*fc*tou1
phi0=-2*pi*fc*tou0
L= ceil(TD*W)
hL= a1.* exp(1j.*phi1).*sinc(L-(tou1.*W))+ a0.* exp (1j.*phi0).*sinc(L-tou0.*W)
plot(t*W,abs(hL))
```

Comment: What's the question? Please read [what topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just, change your code like this.

```
a0=1./(r+v.*t);
a1=1./(2*d-r-v.*t);
```

When you divide scalar by array, `./` is correct operator.